# Changing georef backgound colour

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

Working with a greycale scanned image: when I georef that image it rotates (expected) the blank corners are then filled with black. When the new image overlays I need to make those corners transparent. Obviously I cannot select black as a transparent Colour as the image is greyscale. Is it possible to persuade the GeoRef app to create those blank corners in, say, red - or some other colour so that I can make it transparent?

Allan

Answer (score 2):

haha - got it - I opend the original image and re-saved it after converting from greyscale to 24bit RGB. Then I GeoRef the image. No corner infills visible.